# Register event listener when office addin (Excel) is initialized

Tags: excel, office365, office-js

I would like register event listener let say listener for event when worksheet changed. But listener should be automatically registered when to office addin is initialized.
I have known that with open of the taskpane you can register the listener but this is not my case. Actually what I tried to do is registered event listener when the function file is loaded and not sure if this is correct way. 
I would appreciate any suggestions how can be reached this solution if can be possible.

Here is example of function file.

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />

    <!-- Office JavaScript API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.debug.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../function-file.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- NOTE: The body is empty on purpose. Since function in function-file.js are
       invoked via a button, there is no UI to render. -->
</body>

</html>
```

Typescript file

```
(() => {
  // The initialize function must be run each time a new page is loaded
  Office.initialize = () => {
    $(document).ready(function () {
      registerWorksheetChangedHandler()
      /* the rest of your code here */
    })
  };

  // Add any ui-less function here
})();

//Worksheet changed cell events
function registerWorksheetChangedHandler() {
  Excel.run(function (context) {
    var worksheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet()
    worksheet.onChanged.add(handleWorksheetChanged);

    return context.sync()
        .then(function () {
            console.log("Event handler successfully registered for onWorksheetChanged event in the worksheet.");
        });
}).catch(error => console.log("Error: " + error));
}

function handleWorksheetChanged(event)
{
  return Excel.run(function(context){
        return context.sync()
            .then(function() {
              console.log("Change type of event: " + event.changeType);
              console.log("Address of event: " + event.address);
              console.log("Source of event: " + event.source);
    }).catch(error => console.log("Error: " + error));
  })
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
          xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides"
          xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">

  <!-- Begin Basic Settings: Add-in metadata, used for all versions of Office unless override provided. -->

  <!-- IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in, if you reuse this manifest ensure that you change this id to a new GUID. -->
  <Id>edcf304e-2101-4a0f-8306-7b34608f886a</Id>

  <!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change. -->
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>CSSoft a.s.</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="CSSoft Office Addin" />
  <Description DefaultValue="CSSoft Office Addin"/>

  <!-- Icon for your add-in. Used on installation screens and the add-ins dialog. -->
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>

  <!--If you plan to submit this add-in to the Office Store, uncomment the SupportUrl element below-->
  <!--<SupportUrl DefaultValue="[Insert the URL of a page that provides support information for the app]">-->

  <!-- Domains that will be allowed when navigating. For example, if you use ShowTaskpane and then have an href link, navigation will only be allowed if the domain is on this list. -->
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain1</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain2</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain3</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <!--End Basic Settings. -->

  <!--Begin TaskPane Mode integration. This section is used if there are no VersionOverrides or if the Office client version does not support add-in commands. -->
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Workbook" />
  </Hosts>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/index.html" />
  </DefaultSettings>
  <!-- End TaskPane Mode integration.  -->

  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>

  <!-- Begin Add-in Commands Mode integration. -->
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">

    <!-- The Hosts node is required. -->
    <Hosts>
      <!-- Each host can have a different set of commands. -->
      <!-- Excel host is Workbook, Word host is Document, and PowerPoint host is Presentation. -->
      <!-- Make sure the hosts you override match the hosts declared in the top section of the manifest. -->
      <Host xsi:type="Workbook">
        <!-- Form factor. Currently only DesktopFormFactor is supported. -->
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <!--"This code enables a customizable message to be displayed when the add-in is loaded successfully upon individual install."-->
          <GetStarted>
            <!-- Title of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a ShortString resource -->
            <Title resid="CSSoft.GetStarted.Title"/>

            <!-- Description of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a LongString resource -->
            <Description resid="CSSoft.GetStarted.Description"/>

            <!-- Point to a url resource which details how the add-in should be used. -->
            <LearnMoreUrl resid="CSSoft.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
          </GetStarted>
          <!-- Function file is a HTML page that includes the JavaScript where functions for ExecuteAction will be called.
            Think of the FunctionFile as the code behind ExecuteFunction. -->
          <FunctionFile resid="CSSoft.DesktopFunctionFile.Url" />

          <!-- PrimaryCommandSurface is the main Office Ribbon. -->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
            <!-- Use OfficeTab to extend an existing Tab. Use CustomTab to create a new tab. -->
             <!-- <OfficeTab id="TabHome"> -->
             <CustomTab id="CSSoft.CustomTab">
              <!-- Ensure you provide a unique id for the group. Recommendation for any IDs is to namespace using your company name. -->
              <Group id="CSSoft.Group">
                <!-- Label for your group. resid must point to a ShortString resource. -->
                <Label resid="CSSoft.GroupLabel" />
                <!-- Icons. Required sizes 16,32,80, optional 20, 24, 40, 48, 64. Strongly recommended to provide all sizes for great UX. -->
                <!-- Use PNG icons. All URLs on the resources section must use HTTPS. -->
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="CSSoft.tpicon_16x16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="CSSoft.tpicon_32x32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="CSSoft.tpicon_80x80" />
                </Icon>
                <!-- Menu example -->
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="CSSoft.Menu">
                  <Label resid="CSSoft.Menu.Label" />
                  <Tooltip resid="CSSoft.Menu.Tooltip" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="CSSoft.Menu.Label" />
                    <Description resid="CSSoft.Menu.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                 <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="CSSoft.menu_16x16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="CSSoft.menu_32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="CSSoft.menu_80x80" />
                  </Icon>                
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>CSSoftMenuTaskPaneID</TaskpaneId>
                    <SourceLocation resid="CSSoft.Taskpane.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
             <!--</OfficeTab>-->
            <Label resid="CSSoft.CustomTab.Label" />
            </CustomTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>

    <!-- You can use resources across hosts and form factors. -->
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="CSSoft.tpicon_16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png" />
        <bt:Image id="CSSoft.tpicon_32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png" />
        <bt:Image id="CSSoft.tpicon_80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png" />
        <bt:Image id="CSSoft.menu_16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/menu_16x16.png" />
        <bt:Image id="CSSoft.menu_32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/menu_32x32.png" />
        <bt:Image id="CSSoft.menu_80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/menu_80x80.png" />
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="CSSoft.Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/index.html" />
        <bt:Url id="CSSoft.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=276812" />
        <bt:Url id="CSSoft.DesktopFunctionFile.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/function-file/function-file.html" />
      </bt:Urls>
      <!-- ShortStrings max characters==125. -->
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="CSSoft.TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane" />
        <bt:String id="CSSoft.GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Menu" />
        <bt:String id="CSSoft.GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="Get started with your sample add-in!" />
        <bt:String id="CSSoft.CustomTab.Label" DefaultValue="CSSoft"/>
        <bt:String id="CSSoft.Menu.Label" DefaultValue="Go Menu"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <!-- LongStrings max characters==250. -->
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="CSSoft.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show a Taskpane" />
        <bt:String id="CSSoft.GetStarted.Description" DefaultValue="CSSoft add-in loaded succesfully. Go to the CSSoft tab and click the 'Go Menu' button to get started." />
        <bt:String id="CSSoft.Menu.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Access into the main menu" />
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
  <!-- End Add-in Commands Mode integration. -->

</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: Is your code not working or are you just asking if there's another way to do the same thing? If it works, I think I would do what you are doing.

Comment: I tried it but I do not know actually how can I see the log from console. I do not use Visual Studio but Visual Studio Code and have experience with F12Chooser but I was able just used for taskpane. So this could be the right solution from your point of view ? The function file is always downloaded with manifest when the Excel document is opened ?

Comment: The function.html and function.js do not appear in the F12 tools. To debug them, do your testing in Office on the web and use the browser's F12 tools. For details, see [Sideload Office Add-ins in Office on the web for testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/sideload-office-add-ins-for-testing).

Comment: I can confirm that Excel Web enviroment is better for debugging of the addin. But when I checked downloaded resources I could not find html function file which should be downloaded with the manifest. I have also added my manifest and updated the question. Do you know where could be the problem that the function file is not downloaded with the manifest ?

Comment: The manifest and the html/js files are not downloaded together. The manifest is not hosted on your website. It is either sideloaded when you are developing or it is deployed to a catalog when the add-in is in production. Your manifest shows that you have a button to open a taskpane, but no button to open a function.html and function.js file. Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/excel-tutorial, especially the section on adding a second button. Also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/add-in-commands

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I made it to work so if I understood correctly the function file is loaded in case when user click on ribbon button which is binded to function name in the function file ?